# Python select if rows exist in dataframe that meet two criteria

Tags: python, list, select, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe (df), a list (lst_attract_peds) and a smaller dataframe (df2) that is come from df. I want to check if there are rows in df that df['t']==df2['t'] and df['Ped_id']==(lst_attract_peds). I use the below code:

```
(((df['t'] == float(df2['t'])) & (df['Ped_id'].isin(lst_attract_peds))).any())
```

and the output is true if exists at least one row in df for at least one of the elements in lst_attract_peds. How could I rewrite the code if I want to check if for ALL (not for at least one) the elements in lst_attract_peds exist rows in df?